# Why use assert instead of exception throwing?

Tags: exception, assert

In one of the online courses I am taking on Udacity regarding code debugging, the professor says it's better to use assert instead of exception throwing in the actual code.

Although through out my programming career I have never seen anyone use it.

Do you know why it is in fact? Do you agree?

**PS:** the below image is Python code, but I guess the idea applies to all programming languages. Also, this course is only 4 month old so I imagine the method taught is the most modern approach.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assert is only for debugging, and allows you to check invariants in a one-liner. Asserts and similar macros are used ubiquitously in testing frameworks. With exceptions, you really need to care what the rest of your library or program is doing. Asserts are as simple as it gets.

It will crash the program without any ambiguity as to what caused it - your assert caused it. It is easier to go there in a debugger. An exception may be caught and will not stop the program or may cause side-effects such as stack-unwinding from a place where it wouldn't normally occur, calling all the destructors, etc., when you don't really care about that since you're debugging.

With exceptions, you need to declare functions to throw, must enable exceptions in languages like C++, etc.

If you're debugging interactively and not just running test cases in batch mode, and as your example is in Python, I think you'd find a function that starts pdb and stops the program right there more helpful.

Comment: Not really, when an assertion fails it throws an exception and from the condition of the assertion, you know why it failed. Also, you can surround an assertion with a try catch

Comment: Add to that, you can [disable assertions](http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/01/enable-or-disable-assertion-in-java.html) when you enter production mode.

Comment: Asserts may throw an exception in Python, but you asked generally. And yeah, sure you can disable them. But you couldn't disable exceptions because they're meant to be used in production code, unlike asserts.

Comment: Though technically some languages allow disabling exceptions too for performance reasons. But you could never disable them in a program that needs them for error handling etc. Asserts are impossible to use for error handling in many languages.

Comment: maybe you are right, but you are not saying why asserts are bad or impossible to use?

Comment: Also, asserts are 1 line long where as if else including exceptions are at least 3 lines. So less coding with asserts

Comment: since asserts are for development phase only, why not just put a break point at the line in question, and then remove the break point when you see that it is ok ...